# Remove all elements before active element and append to bottom

Tags: jquery, dom

i have a container DIV with children DIVs like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="one" class="child"></div>
    <div id="two" class="child"></div>
    <div id="three" class="child"></div>
    <div id="four" class="child active"></div>
    <div id="five" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

what i want is that all child DIV before `.active` child DIV will be removed and will be appended at the bottom, so it will now look like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="four" class="child active"></div>
    <div id="five" class="child"></div>
    <div id="one" class="child"></div>
    <div id="two" class="child"></div>
    <div id="three" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

How can i do that in jquery?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this :

```
$('div:lt('+$('.active').index()+')', '.parent').appendTo('.parent');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyZZD/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.active').nextAll().addBack().prependTo('.parent');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hyZZD/4/)**

No cloning, no string concatenation, and no `.each()`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -

```
var $cloned = $('.parent .active').prevAll().clone().end().remove();
$('.parent').append($cloned.get().reverse());
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/AqS4u/1/

Answer (score 1):

In case there are multiple of these `divs`:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
    $(this.firstChild).nextUntil('.active').appendTo(this);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wc2g/)

Comment: No need for `.each()` on this one.

Comment: Not for the example. That's why I wrote: *"In case there are multiple of these divs:"*

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('.active').prevAll().appendTo('.parent');
```

**EDIT** actually, not, but I'll leave here for posterity - the `.prevAll()` collection is returned in reverse order, so the append doesn't work out right.

Comment: I get 4,5,3,2,1 not 4,5,1,2,3.

Comment: yeah, I'm looking into that now.  Puzzling, since I thought jQuery collections were always in document order.

Comment: prevAll selects in the opposite order, tried it as well, and only thing I could come up with was `$($('.active').prevAll().get().reverse()).appendTo('.parent');`